# How to automatically run a shell script after activation of python virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

in a virtual python environment called `venv` I always need to add a variable to my `PATH` variable. I only want it when `venv` is activated.
Can I create a script and tell my `venv` to always run it when activating my `venv`?

Thanks :)

I am using [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) virtual environment and `ubuntu 20.04`.

My python version is `Python 3.8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `<venv>/bin/activate` and add your `$PATH`. `deactivate` will automatically remove it because it restores `$PATH` that `activate` saved.